# Browser error: "file could not be saved because the source file could not be read" when using Windows 10 VPN

Tags: vpn, browser

On my Windows 10 computer I use a PPTP VPN connection. When downloading a file via my browser I get the message "file could not be saved because the source file could not be read" message. I tried several browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge), same result.

If I disconnect the VPN, the problem goes away. I haven't seen anything online addressing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft VPN (PPTP)? That is not split tunnel, so it cuts off network traffic outside the tunnel. That looks like what you have.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows VPN"? To what kind VPN "type" are you using? What do you want to use the VPN for? Most likely the VPN server you are connecting to is not set up to "handle internet traffic".

Comment: it's the MS VPN that's built into Windows. It is, as @John says, PPTP. Browsing seems to work fine. It's just file downloading that usually breaks. I say "usually" because I saw once where it did work.

Comment: MS VPN prevents traffic flow outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played around with PPTP too much but "simply speaking" your VPN provider (the person/organisation that is managing the VPN server) seem to block either that "type of traffic" or the servers you are trying to download the files from.

So you have essentially three choices:

- talk to the VPN service provider
- disable VPN for "those downloads"
- setup your Windows so only "those downloads" don't go through the VPN connection

The setup for the third options depends on the specifics of what and why it gets block. Or what you **want** to use the VPN connection for e.g. only accessing your work's intranet (I hope not, since PPTP is not secure anymore).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get hold of the IT consultant that set up the VPN. The problem was that the connection was set to use the default gateway on the remote network. To fix the problem,

- Go to Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings.
- Right click on the VPN connection and choose Properties.
- In the VPN's Properties window, click the Networking tab, select Internet Protocol Version 4 and click Properties.
- In the TCP/IPv4 properties window, click Advanced.
- In the Advanced TCP/IP settings window, unselect "Use default gateway on remote network".

Click Ok successively to get out and it should be good.

Comment: Note: this essentially means that you disabled all "internet traffic" for your VPN, not only the file download. If the network you connect to via VPN uses more the one subnet, it won't be accessible as well. This is not a "general" solution and might not work for other users.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could explain exactly HOW a change in networking settings manages to fix an issue apparently related to a filesystem / file access glitch. It says "file could not be read", not "host could not be reached" or "hostname could not be resolved" or anything like that.